# XMLHttpRequest cannot load. No Access-Control-Allow-Origin only on POST call and only through actual local website

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, servicestack, xmlhttprequest

I see a lot of requests about this,  looked a bit and didn't see my particular issue but I very well could have missed it.  Apologies if so.

I'm making a website that calls out to a service stack service.  The service is published and hosted on a server.

I encountered this error earlier when trying to make a GET call to the service and found that adding this

```
            base.SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig
        {
            GlobalResponseHeaders = {
        { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" },
        { "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" },
        { "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type" },
        },
        });
```

Resolved the issue.  Now however when making an ajax call via the site

```
$.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "https://pirates.com/SHIPSWS/shipDemo",
                    data: {
                        "Bow": $("#BowTypes").val(),
                        "BodyContent": CKEDITOR.instances.body.getData()
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        EmailBody = data;
                    }
                })
```

I get the same error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://pirates.com/SHIPSWS/shipDemo. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:58032' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Which confuses me since I set the above and the GET statements that are called prior in the website through ajax work like a charm.

What further confuses me is that if I use say, the postman add on for chrome to make an actual post request to the service.  It works without issue.

Would anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Edit #1

Headers via chrome when calling from the local website.

```
Request URL:https://pirates.com/SHIPSWS/shipDemo
Request Headers CAUTION: Provisional headers are shown.
Accept:*/*
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Origin:http://localhost:58032
Referer:http://localhost:58032/Default.aspx
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
Bow:Front
BodyContent:<p>Yarrrrrrr Matey</p>
```

Edit #2  Working Get Call In The Site

```
 $.ajax
            ({
                url: "https://pirates.com/SHIPSWS/shipDemo/ships/" + this.value + "?format=json",
                success: function (data) {
                    ShipList = data;
                         Emails = $("#EmailTable").dataTable({
                        "bDestroy": true,
                        "aaData": ShipList ,
                        "aoColumns": [
                            {
                                "sTitle": "Email Address",
                                "mData": "emailAddress"
                            },
                            {
                                "sTitle": "First Name",
                                "mData": "firstName"
                            },
                            {
                                "sTitle": "Last Name",
                                "mData": "lastName"
                            },
                            {
                                "sTitle": "Ship Number",
                                "mData": "shipNumber"
                            },
                            {
                                "sTitle": "Shipsize",
                                "mData": "shipsize"
                            },
                            {
                                "sTitle": "Select",
                                "mData": "emailAddress",
                                "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                                    return '<input type="checkbox" class="check1" name="check1" value="' + data + '">';
                                },
                            }
                        ]
                    });
```

Comment: Start by using your favourite browser debugging/developer tools to check the headers sent and received during the POST, it'll help you to find on which side there may be something to fix.

Comment: Does your **server** handle [preflighted `OPTIONS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) requests correctly?

Comment: Can you show an example of a working GET request?

Comment: Website is http,  however again website is able to successfully do GET call with service.

Comment: Well,  interesting note,  when I take out the data field in the call,  the call is successful and the success function kicks off.  So it's something I'm sending over maybe?  Specifically it's what I'm sending in the BodyContent....  CKEditor....  which is just <p>Yarrrrrrr Matey</p>

Comment: I wanted to send that raw text (the text is going to the service and is replacing text that is also html).   Ended up figuring out the cause though. Posting answer shortly,  thanks all for the help!

Comment: i fail at reading request headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after playing with it some more,  the post call would send

Yarrrrrrr Matey

as part of it's data (the BodyContent).  This was causing the error.

I ended up grabbing this function from another question on here

```
        function htmlEncode(value) {
        //create a in-memory div, set it's inner text(which jQuery automatically encodes)
        //then grab the encoded contents back out.  The div never exists on the page.
        return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
    }
```

and encoded my one part of the ajax call

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "https://pirates.com/SHIPSWS/shipDemo",
                data: {
                    "Bow": $("#BowTypes").val(),
                    "BodyContent": htmlEncode(CKEDITOR.instances.body.getData())
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    EmailBody = data;
                }
            })
```

and it now works like a charm.  Thanks for the help everyone!

(To decode the html just use this on the data in the service)

```
function htmlDecode(value){
  return $('<div/>').html(value).text();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you have access to the service, i.e. are you the owner? The owner of the service needs to allow your origin (your domain) in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header part.

So on the service you're calling make sure a header is set `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://yourdomain.com"`.

Comment: I am the owner of the service,  the GET call to the service from the site works fine,  I believe the base.setconfig portion in my question should be taking care of POST calls as well.